# How to group an array of objects according to a property in that object

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects like these

```
[
{
        id: 536,
        user_id: 87,
        event_type: 'CA',
        purpose: 1,
        timestamp: 1435678384
      },
      {
        id: 5368,
        user_id: 87,
        event_type: 'CA',
        purpose: 4,
        timestamp: 1435678384
      },
      {
        id: 53688,
        user_id: 87,
        event_type: 'CA',
        purpose: 9,
        timestamp: 1435678385
      },
      {
        id: 588,
        user_id: 87,
        event_type: 'CA',
        purpose: 7,
        timestamp: 1435678386
      },
      {
        id: 588,
        user_id: 87,
        event_type: 'CA',
        purpose: 5,
        timestamp: 1435678396
      },
      {
        id: 588,
        user_id: 87,
        event_type: 'CA',
        purpose: 8,
        timestamp: 1435678397
      },
      {
        id: 588,
        user_id: 87,
        event_type: 'CA',
        purpose: 2,
        timestamp: 1435678398
      },
      {
        id: 588,
        user_id: 87,
        event_type: 'CA',
        purpose: 3,
        timestamp: 1435678350
      }
]
```

I want to group all the objects inside the array by their **timestamp**, so if the timestamps in the objects are located within 5ms of each other, combine the objects into one single array

So in this case I want the output to look like

```
[
    [{
            id: 536,
            user_id: 87,
            event_type: 'CA',
            purpose: 1,
            timestamp: 1435678384
        },
        {
            id: 5368,
            user_id: 87,
            event_type: 'CA',
            purpose: 4,
            timestamp: 1435678384
        },
        {
            id: 53688,
            user_id: 87,
            event_type: 'CA',
            purpose: 9,
            timestamp: 1435678385
        },
        {
            id: 588,
            user_id: 87,
            event_type: 'CA',
            purpose: 7,
            timestamp: 1435678386
        }
    ],
    [{
            id: 588,
            user_id: 87,
            event_type: 'CA',
            purpose: 5,
            timestamp: 1435678396
        },
        {
            id: 588,
            user_id: 87,
            event_type: 'CA',
            purpose: 8,
            timestamp: 1435678397
        },
        {
            id: 588,
            user_id: 87,
            event_type: 'CA',
            purpose: 2,
            timestamp: 1435678398
        }
    ], {
        id: 588,
        user_id: 87,
        event_type: 'CA',
        purpose: 3,
        timestamp: 1435678350
    }
]
```

I have tried to use an array method filter on this to get the desired code. However I can only segregate one group, I cannot have a 2D array like this. Notice the last object which cannot be grouped(timestamp is far beyond 5ms of any other object's timestamp) is not in an array.

My efforts so far are not much, Here is what I have tried

```
ca.forEach((cur, index) => {
            let newArr = []
            let grouped = ca.filter((target, innerIndex) => {
                    if ((cur.timestamp - target.timestamp) < 5) {
                    return true
                } else {
                    return false
                }
            })
```

Any help to solve this will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You've wrote one more closing brace here: `if (cur.timestamp - target.timestamp) < 5) {`... Is this a typo?

Comment: yes sorry, let me fix it, I needed to add one brace

Comment: Note that objectA can be within 5min of objectB, which can be within 5 of objectC.  Should we group these, even if objectC is > 5min from objectA?  There are sophisticated approaches to clustering by time, is that what you're looking for? In simple form, the algorithm that clusters by timestamp will be dependent on the order of the input array.

Comment: Hi lara, Object c should not be grouped with objecta if their timestamps are 5min apart. The basic idea here is group all objects within 5mins of each other

Comment: @archnemesis, how would you group 3 objects that are at times 12:00am, 12:03am, and 12:06am?

Comment: so in this case, 1st and 2nd will be grouped and the 3rd one wont be grouped with the first 2, assuming those are the only elements in the array. If there is another object with ts, 12.07 am then the third object will be grouped with 4th

Comment: Are you okay with -- by your logic -- an input array with the same objects ordered in reverse 12:06, 12:03, and 12:00 will produce a different grouping?

Comment: assume that the array is sorted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can try is the [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function: [see here my code in stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-u2ww68)

```js
var firstArray = [
{
        id: 536,
        user_id: 87,
        event_type: 'CA',
        purpose: 1,
        timestamp: 1435678384
      },
      {
        id: 5368,
        user_id: 87,
        event_type: 'CA',
        purpose: 4,
        timestamp: 1435678384
      },
      {
        id: 53688,
        user_id: 87,
        event_type: 'CA',
        purpose: 9,
        timestamp: 1435678385
      },
      {
        id: 588,
        user_id: 87,
        event_type: 'CA',
        purpose: 7,
        timestamp: 1435678386
      },
      {
        id: 588,
        user_id: 87,
        event_type: 'CA',
        purpose: 5,
        timestamp: 1435678396
      },
      {
        id: 588,
        user_id: 87,
        event_type: 'CA',
        purpose: 8,
        timestamp: 1435678397
      },
      {
        id: 588,
        user_id: 87,
        event_type: 'CA',
        purpose: 2,
        timestamp: 1435678398
      },
      {
        id: 588,
        user_id: 87,
        event_type: 'CA',
        purpose: 3,
        timestamp: 1435678350
      }
];

var secondArray = firstArray.sort((a, b)=>{
    return a.timestamp-b.timestamp
}).reduce(
  (accumulator,current)=>{
    if(
      typeof accumulator[accumulator.length-1]==='object' &&
      current.timestamp - accumulator[accumulator.length-1][0].timestamp <5
    ) {
      accumulator[accumulator.length-1].push(current);
    } else {
      accumulator.push([current]);
    }
    return accumulator;
  },
  []
);


console.log(secondArray);
```

**EDIT: I didn't see the 5 ms need but you can adapt the `if` to suit your need, tell me if you want me to do it. ;)**

**EDIT2: I added the sort function in order to sort by timestamp like that we're sure the minus operation is in the good order and I did the minus operation in the if of the reduce. Let me know if that helps**

Comment: would be great if you  can edit it :) thanks for the help so far

Comment: thanks , this is perfect, just out of curiosity, do you have a solution using filter?

Comment: it works flawless, but I am having trouble understanding reduce.

Comment: I want the ungrouped elements to be in the first array and not enclosed in an array itself. How can I make that work?

Comment: Hi @archnemesis, sorry for the late answer, but for the filter, you would have to manage some temporary variables I think, even if a foreach would be more approriate/simpler IMO. For the ungrouped elements in the first array you can add right after the reduce a map function : `.reduce(...).map((item)=> item.length > 1 ? item : item[0]);`

Answer (score 0):

You can create one big  array. And small reusable array that you put all the objects that are related and then  push the tempArray to the allArray Array and clear it and then do the same for all the other objects. Get all the object with that certain property using the foreach method of the array.

Let allArray = [ ];

Let tempArray = [ ];

allArray.push(tempArray);